# SnappyGuide Location API - Geojson

Tags: geojson, geocode

Does SnappyGuide Location APIs provide support for Geojson? i am planning to show them in maps? 
Eg: http://api.snappyguide.com:4080/user/places/geocode?location=37.3215138883855,-122.000224407319&content_type=subunit

I do not see any reference to GeoJson in the doc [here](http://snappyguide.com/doc/places/geocode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SnappyGuide Reverse Geocode](http://snappyguide.com/doc/places/geocode) APIs support Geojson formats. Please add format=geojson to the your API ie., http://api.snappyguide.com:4080/user/places/geocode?location=37.3215138883855,-122.000224407319&content_type=subunit&format=geojson .